Jenkins Plugin for Email Notification in MultiBranch Pipeline
We are using Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline and with Email Extension plugin we can send email notifications via Jenkins file : https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/#Email-extplugin-PipelineExamples
But, Is there a way to trigger emails in Multibranch pipeline configuration ? No by writing scripts.
Trigger email notifications to recipients based on branch and GitLab user who caused the build failure.
